# copy files within azure blob container using python

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I am using the azure-sdk for python to copy a blob in the same container. But I am getting authentication error.

the source code is:

```
status = None
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(storage_account_connection_string)
copied_blob = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(containerName, 'test.csv')
result = copied_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_url=source_blob, requires_sync=True)
print(result)
status = result['copy_status']
if status != "success":
    for i in range(1000):
        props = copied_blob.get_blob_properties()
        status = props.copy.status
        print("Copy status: " + status)
        if status == "success":
            # copy finished
            break
        time.sleep(60*0.5)
```

And I am getting the error:

> ClientAuthenticationError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
> Time:2024-01-10T14:36:11.9520689Z
> ErrorCode:CannotVerifyCopySource
> Content: `CannotVerifyCopySource`Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
> Time:2024-01-10T14:36:11.9520689Z

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure-sdk for python to copy a blob in the same container

Use the below Python code to copy a blob in the same container using Azure SDK for Python.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = "xxxx"
container_name = "block-image"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

source_blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, "bike.png")
destination_blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, "Adventure.png")
copy_operation = destination_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(source_blob_client.url)
copy_status = destination_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy.status

while copy_status != "success":
    copy_status = destination_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy.status
print("Copy status: " + copy_status)
```

**Output:**

```
Copy status: success
```

[image: Copy operation successful]

**Portal:**

[image: Blob storage in the Azure portal]

**Reference:**

[azure.storage.blob.BlobClient class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-start-copy-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the Microsoft official documentation for [BlobServiceClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python), you should either create a SAS ([Shared Access Signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview)). This SAS uri can be created in the Azure portal inside of the container in the Security + networking section.

[image]

Other solution is to input the credential string parameter for the [from_connection_string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobserviceclient-from-connection-string) method. The value can be any of the following credential types as defined by the aformentioned documentation:

> The value can be a SAS token string, an instance of a AzureSasCredential or AzureNamedKeyCredential from azure.core.credentials, an account shared access key, or an instance of a TokenCredentials class from azure.identity.